# Twilio ClientQuickstart not working as intended

Tags: javascript, c#, twilio

I am having trouble with [the Twilio ClientQuickstart project for C#/js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/client/javascript). According to Twilio support, the project should work "out of the box", but it does not for me. I want to be able to call from a phone to the browser, and from the browser to a phone, and talk to the people on each end (not having the computer reading me a message). I have tried a number of changes without success, so now I am back to the original project where the only additions are the appsettings in local config. TwilioAccountSid, TwilioAuthToken and TwilioTwimlAppSid are correct, and TwilioCallerId are set to my twilio phonenumber. The setup is ok and the device is ready before each call.

Right now I'm using ngrok to host the site. Voice request url on the twiml app in twilio console is set to the provided url from ngrok, with /voice.

Neither calling in nor out to talk to a person is working. When calling out from the browser to a phone, I only hear the automated 'Congratulations'-message from twilio. This is the exact same result I get if I put no number at all in the 'make a call'-textbox.

When calling the twilionumber, I hear the ringing in my phone but nothing happens in the browser. Debugging shows that the Index method of the VoiceController is called repeatedly, generating a lot of response objects, until the call times out. This results in a list of incoming/outgoing calls in the twilio console call log, where the first 'from' is my phonenumber (and twilionumber as 'to'), and the rest has the twilionumber both as from and to, bouncing between 'incoming' and 'outgoing dial' every second.

```
public ActionResult Index(VoiceRequest request) {

    var callerId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioCallerId"];
    var response = new TwilioResponse();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.To)) {
        // wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
        // by checking if the number given has only digits and format symbols
        if (Regex.IsMatch(request.To, "^[\\d\\+\\-\\(\\) ]+$")) {
            response.Dial(new Number(request.To), new { callerId });
        }
        else {
            response.Dial(new Client(request.To), new { callerId });
        }
    }
    else {
        response.Say("Thanks for calling!");
    }
    return TwiML(response);
}
```

I have searched but can not seem to find any information on this type of problem anywhere. Would be very grateful if someone could shed some light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When [dialling from the browser](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/client/javascript) you need to make sure you enter a real phone number or other client name in the browser application.

[image]

This line: `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.To)) {` is checking that the incoming request has a number or client that it is trying to dial to. If you don't enter anything it will just fall through to the congratulations message. IF you are entering a number to dial, can you log or debug to see if there is a number being sent?

On the other hand, if you try to call your Twilio number from an external phone then again, the number will then keep trying to dial itself, as you've witnessed.

This quick start is intended to get you going making and receiving calls in the browser, either to other browsers or the phone network. You will need to do a bit more work to get incoming calls from the phone network to happen in your browser.

What you could do is, if the incoming `request.To` is your Twilio number, then return TwiML to [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) to a [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client) name that you know is logged in right now.

Comment: Thank you Phil, the 'dial' to a 'client' worked! But what is the correct way of doing this? (I just assume there is a better way since you say "what you could do, is...").

On outgoing calls, I am entering a real phone number, and I have tried several different numbers. 

When trying to call, the output window in the testproject prints this:

> Requesting Capability Token...
> Got a token.
> Twilio.Device Ready!
> Successfully established call!
> Hanging up...
> Call ended.

The javascript prints the number out to the console, but only the 'congratulation' is heard.

Comment: If you want to check out a more complete project, more than just the QuickStart, then take at look at this tutorial on [making calls with Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/browser-calls/csharp/mvc).

Comment: I have same problem with calling out from the BrowserCalls project as I had with the quickstart. I have created a ticket with a real phonenumber, and try to call it from the dashboard. According to the tutorial, twilio will pass the phonenumber to /Call/Connect (the request url). I set a breakpoint in the Connect method in the CallController, but it is never reached. I see the number is correct, based on the updates of the call status.

When trying to call from my phone to the browser (viewing the Dashboard, as support_agent), the Connect method is called and the call comes through.

Comment: What's the JavaScript you're using to set the phone number when initiating the call from the browser?

Comment: The original, from the browser-calls project:

function callCustomer(phoneNumber) {
    var params = { "phoneNumber": phoneNumber };
    Twilio.Device.connect(params);
}

Initiated by this button:
                        <button onclick="callCustomer('@ticket.PhoneNumber')" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg call-customer-button">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            Call customer
                        </button>

Comment: Can you add this to your question, it's hard to read code samples in comments.